# Running Windows install on real HW through Linux VirtualBox Host

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, virtualbox, virtualization

Assume a box with both Linux and Windows installed on real hardware. Is there any way of booting the Linux and starting the Windows system via VirtualBox or some other virtualization framework from there?

Comment: You may perhaps wish to read also my answer, there is a chance you may have your wish granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A VBox Guest and a baremetal install would have dramatically different driver sets. windows would not react well to this. its like swapping out the motherboard ever other boot.

Answer (score 2):

The two answers you received are, by and large, right. However, I would like to add that VMWare can, under some conditions, be used to boot a Windows system installed on a physical partition as a VM guest.

On [this Web page of the VMWare site](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_dualscsi_ws.html#1046391) you can find stated:

> It may be possible to configure VMware Workstation so that you can use an operating system already installed and configured on a SCSI disk as a guest operating system inside a VMware Workstation virtual machine.

The somewhat stringent condition under which this is possible is the following:

> Using an existing SCSI disk — or SCSI raw disk — inside a virtual machine is supported only if the host has an LSI Logic or BusLogic SCSI adapter. LSI Logic is the preferred choice because it is easier to find drivers for LSI Logic adapters

The article I referenced above goes on to give extremely detailed explanations of the whole process, including information on where to find drivers for the LSI logic controllers. The instructions are way too complex to be summarized here.

Alternatively, if you have an IDE disk, the whole process is much simpler: [the VMWare Web site gives here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_dualboot_ws.html) instructions on how to do it. Please notice however that these instructions are available only for Windows guests from 95 to XP. From Vista on, there are no instructions available, and you are left on your own.

I thought it worth noting that, even though the previous answers are overall correct, there is still a small windows of opportunity for those willing to put the effort into it.

Comment: Likewise, Parallels on a Mac has the ability to run a physical Bootcamp Windows install as a VM.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank Thomas said, there's no known way to manage such install. 
But maybe you'll use another solution which is booting Windows image with user data and files mapped to linux data and files (you need to configure shared folders inside win virtual machine pointing to outside "real world" linux folders). I use this solution for compiling windows executables for wxpython sources developed on debian, and integration works quite nice.

Comment: Thanks @GMGray, that's exactly what i'm going to do. I'm running Linux and need to use Win occasionally and running it in VBox is my most frequent use case. I just wondered if i could also have an option to run the same Win on bare metal without the performance penalty of a virtual host. To avoid the other option of buying another Win license that would allow me for another installation. Seems this was a long shot, and i missed :D Thanx guys.